# Join different columns from different tables (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 8 different tables and I would like to select only specific columns in one query. If I use this query I have wrong results :(

```
SELECT a.entity_id id
     , a.field_imie_value imie
     , c.field_nazwisko_value nazwisko
     , d.field_preferencja_1_value preferencja1
     , e.field_preferencja_2_value preferencja2
     , f.field_preferencja_3_value preferencja3
     , g.field_nr_niu_value nr_niu
     , h.dystans odleglosc
     , i.field_sytuacja_value sytuacja   
  FROM field_data_field_imie a
  JOIN field_data_field_nazwisko c
     , field_data_field_preferencja_1 d
     , field_data_field_preferencja_2 e
     , field_data_field_preferencja_3 f
     , field_data_field_nr_niu g
     , field_data_field_adres h
     , field_data_field_sytuacja i
 WHERE a.entity_id = b.entity_id 
   AND a.entity_id=c.entity_id
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Why do you have a long list of tables in the `from` clause with no join conditions on them?

Comment: MySQL. There are relational tables entity_id are always the same

Comment: @TomazK . . . and the database engine is supposed to guess that you intend an `inner join` instead of the `cross join` as specified by the use of a `,` in the `from` clause.  A simple rule:  just don't use commas in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

When you use joining tables you must use syntax similar to :

```
select A.field1 from table1 AS A inner join table2 as B on A.field1 = B.field1
```

Comment: Thanks for help :) But how should I join more then 2 tables? This works: select A.entity_id, A.field_imie_value, B.field_nazwisko_value from field_data_field_imie AS A inner join field_data_field_nazwisko as B on A.entity_id = B.entity_id but how join next columns from different tables?

Answer (score 0):

syntax should be like this;

```
SELECT *  
FROM field_data_field_imie a
JOIN field_data_field_nazwisko c on (a.entity_id=c.entity_id)
JOIN table x on (x.column=a.entitiy_id)
```

or you shouldn't use join at all.

Answer (score 0):

actually number of tables is the important thing not how many fields you want however this is the syntax for joining more table :
elect A.field1 from table1 AS A inner join table2 as B on A.field1 = B.field1 inner join table3 AS C on table1.field1 = C.field1

and syntax for more joining is similar